# hide() jQuery does it reset the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, show-hide

I have a question when using the jQuery `.hide()` function to hide a input by ID, does it reset the field/select value to `[0]` or `val('')` or empty etc? reason I ask is because if a user shows a field, populates it, then realises he/she made the wrong decision on a input that has a show/hide condition. when they go to hide the field again, that value will still exist right?

What would be the most ideal way to prevent unnecessary values coming through on `.hide()` inputs?

Note: I have some hidden inputs that always pass a value for backend process's but these form types are hidden always.

Comment: This is the sort of thing you can discover by just trying things in the browser developer console. The `.hide()` and `.show()` methods will not affect the value of input elements.

Comment: so is it best practise to remove values on inputs that have the hide() function triggered?

Comment: It depends on how you want your user interface to work; there is no single answer. If the values have sensitive personal information, then you may want to clear them out to reassure your users that your software is careful with personal information. If not, then it may be more convenient to leave the values alone.

Comment: but the thing is, if the values are inputted then hidden, they were hidden because they were not required, so technically if that value still went through when not needed, it would only confuse my users. This is why I raised my question.

Comment: You can always toggle the `disabled` property when you hide the elements. That way the values will not be submitted with the form, but they will remain in the DOM if the elements are shown again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hide()` function will only hide the element (by toggling the `display` style).

If you want to prevent the value to be sent, also disable the input.

```
$('input').prop('disabled', true).hide();
```

or reactivate it

```
$('input').prop('disabled', false).show();
```

Comment: This is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

**.hide() and .show() methods will not affect the value of input elements**

The hide() method hides the selected elements.

**Tip:** This is similar to the CSS property display:none.

**Note:** Hidden elements will not be displayed at all (no longer affects the layout of the page).

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_hide.asp)